# Is there a method in .NET for socket I/O multiplexing that supports async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, async-await

I want to make a high performance server for custom tcp-based protocol in C# (.NET). When I did things like this in C on Linux, I used functions like [`pselect()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect) and [`epoll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) to multiplex sockets efficiently. But in .NET I found only one such method: [`Socket.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.select?view=net-6.0) that similar to old POSIX [`select()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

By the way, System.Net.Sockets namespace has also [`Socket.Poll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.poll?view=net-6.0) method, but I don't consider it, because for some reason it isn't similar to POSIX [`poll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html): it works only with one socket instead of set of file descriptors.

So there is only one suitable method [`Socket.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.select?view=net-6.0) in System.Net.Sockets, but like his POSIX analog it blocks whole thread while waiting for ready I/O operations on sockets set. And this would be fine, unless C# preached the `async/await` approach for all blocking I/O operations, which allows you not to block the thread completely. Therefore, it seems rather strange that .NET does not offer any awaitable method for multiplexing that would work something like this:

```cs
async Task ProcessSocketsReadingAsync(IList checkRead)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
    await Socket.SelectAsync(checkRead, null, null, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    ...
}
```

instead of classic and full thread blocking:

```cs
void ProcessSocketsReading(IList checkRead)
{
    Socket.SelectAsync(checkRead, null, null, 1000);
    ...
}
```

In conclusion, are there methods in the .NET that allow you to do something like `Task ProcessSocketsReadingAsync()` as in example above?

Comment: If you're looking for low-level high performance, async/await isn't going to help much. Having a dedicated thread will perform better, it just doesn't scale the same and getting the multithreading right is harder. But sometimes if you need guaranteed responsiveness and high throughput, it's the way to go. For example, I use a dedicated Thread to capture video frames. It's one thread, for the life of the application, that is *always* busy. In that case async/await doesn't help. So I'd say that the reason async methods don't exist is because they don't help your use case.

Comment: I might not be correct on this so please someone correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I know the best way to do this is by implementing the SocketAsyncEventArgs pattern with async, then just passing any read/write functionality off to a job system in a separate thread as to not slow down comms. But I am not too familiar with multiplexing in C# so may be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried https://chronoxor.github.io/NetCoreServer/?

Comment: [Asynchronous Client Socket - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) (IAsyncResult) -- [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/) (async/await)

Comment: @Jimi: methods in your example works only with one socket, but question is about multiplexing set of sockets

Comment: @JeremyLakeman how this server works? Didn't find in documentation any info about multiplexing or concrete non-blocking methods. And in code examples interfaces and main operations doesn't have any Task results value.

Comment: On Windows isn't it more common to use ReadAsync and WriteAsync? You don't need `epoll` when you have Overlapped I/O!

Comment: @user253751 it's widely used, but it's not optimal for huge clients count. Multiplexing is better in this case. It's how nginx works, for example.

Comment: What I've heard is that I/O Completion Ports (which ReadAsync/WriteAsync presumably uses but I'm not sure) are overall better than select (actually I think epoll was not available at the time I read about it). But for some reason I can't find any benchmark results online

Comment: @DenisBabarykin: Windows OVERLAPPED I/O works just fine with multiplexing -- you pass an event handle in the OVERLAPPED structure, the operation signals that event when complete, you wait on a large number of these events simultaneously using `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` (for sockets) or `(Msg)WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)` (for all kernel fd-like objects)

Answer (score 3):

The Windows (almost-) equivalent of `epoll` is I/O Completion Ports. In .NET there is one process-wide IOCP instance provided, and it's part of the thread pool. Note that on Windows, I/O *operations* are registered with the IOCP rather than handles.

There is no need for an explicit check (`select` / `epoll_wait`) because the thread pool manages I/O threads that are all associated with the IOCP, and they are always listening for and picking up any available work.

For the vast majority of applications, this Just Works, and you can use the `*Async` methods and be happy. On older platforms (before `ValueTask<T>` existed), this does cause memory allocations (for `Task`/`OVERLAPPED`) for every I/O call. This also (often but not always) includes a thread switch from an I/O thread to a worker thread before continuing your `async` method. In the general case, though, this is efficient enough for most applications.

If you are on an older platform (and unable to use the `ValueTask<T>` Socket APIs), then you can write your own pooling/reuse code around the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` APIs. That will avoid the memory allocations.

If you want to avoid the (possible) thread switch from I/O to worker threads, then you'd probably need to write your own p/Invokes for a custom IOCP type and do all your own thread management, too.